# How to sign a modded apk on mac with apktool

Tags: android, macos, apk, signing, apktool

I have created a modded apk using apktool but when I try to install it , it doesn't install. When I rechecked and compared it with an older apk I found out that my apk file wasn't signed. I searched a lot but couldn't find out a method to sign apk on mac OS X. Please help

Comment: [This documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) should provide you the information about signing your APK in both Android Studio and ADT for Eclipse.

Comment: thanks ztan your link helped. I have posted the solution below

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Got my solution- I use keytool, Jarsigner and zipalign from JDK by using following commands in terminal

To generate keystore

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-keystore.keystore -alias name_alias -keyalg RSA -validity 10000
```

To sign an apk

```
jarsigner -verbose -keystore <path of my-keystore.keystore> <path of apk>  name_alias
```

To zip align an apk

```
zipalign -f -v 4 <your.apk >  <your_aligned.apk>
```

Comment: can you clarify what your.apk and your_aligned.apk are? I have an app-debug.apk and an app-release-unsigned.apk after the first two steps, but which one is which in step 3?

Comment: if you are having an unsigned apk then you can start at step 2 if you already generated a keystore. In my case your.apk was a signed apk and your_aligned.apk was a zip aligned format.

Comment: Ok, I had a misunderstanding. I'll add the note that would have been helpful to me here in case anyone else has the same confusion. <your_aligned.apk> is the file that the zipalign tool outputs and you can name it whatever you'd like.

Answer (score 6):

MacBook User.

1.You need to create .keystore file in terminal. Put on Folder the .Keystore and Your .Apk

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -validity 10000
```

-Its ok to change alias_name and my-release-key but not .keystore

2.Put this on Terminal.

```
jarsigner -verbose -keystore <your .keystore> space <your app file> space <your alias name on creating keystore>
```

then ask you Enter Password put your password in created keystore . Now you have signed apk.

Note: you have JDK Install on your MacBook.

Comment: Thanks its worked and save my hours. Have a good day

Answer (score 3):

If the apk file is already signed, remove the original sign with following code

```
Zip -d <path of apk> META-INF/*
```

To sign an apk

```
jarsigner -verbose -keystore <path of my-keystore.keystore> <path of apk>  alias_name
```

To sign an apk not work and idk >=1.7

```
jarsigner -verbose  -digestalg SHA1 -sigalg MD5withRSA -keystore <path of my-keystore.keystore> <path of apk>  alias_name
```

To zip align an apk

```
 ~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/xxxxx/zipalign -f -v 4 <your.apk >  <your_aligned.apk>
```